# How to set the ServicePort in launchsettings.json for docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

So recently docker-integration in VS2017 has removed the docker project and simply works from `launchsettings.json` and a `Dockerfile`.

In my `launchsettings.json` I have the following:

```
"Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/swagger"
    }
```

Whenever I debug the application a random port is assigned.

If I include a valid sslPort in the `iisExpress` settings it takes the correct http and https ports from there, however my application is not currently using https so I'd rather not bind an unused port.

---

The below iisExpress settings seem to influence the docker settings. While below gives me what I want (a consistent binding from 81:80, host:container) I would prefer that port 444 was not also bound, or that the settings within another profile influence a different profile.

```
"iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:81/",
      "sslPort": 444 (takes a random port if set to 0)
    }
```

Any ideas? I would just like to be able to set the `ServicePort` / default port to a known value.

Answer (score 5):

The Docker section in launchsettings.json supports now `httpPort` and `sslPort` settings:

```
"Docker": {
      ... 
    "httpPort": 8080
}
```